# Bolivian looking to work in Brazil

Tags: us-citizens, visa, brazil, bolivian-citizen

A friend of mine, born in Bolivia and raised in the US (thus holds dual citizenship to both countries) would like to go to Brazil to begin working as an English teacher. The school that we've been in talks with in Sao Carlos seem to think that because she hold a Bolivian passport, she is able to obtain a two year residency permit for Brazil, and she doesn't have to jump through the hoops that other foreigners do, such as signing up for a university course in order to apply for Vitem 4 (see here: http://miami.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/student.xml).

We've had mixed responses from different Brazilian embassies, with some saying that she is eligible but then others saying she isn't. Has anybody any advice for us?

Comment: Is your question how to get a visa or residence permit or something else?

Comment: She'd like to get a work visa. We both would like to go to teach English for the year, and have been directed towards Vitem 4 by our prospective employer as the best way to obtain a visa.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to add more details?

Comment: She can speak Portuguese ? Can be easier

Answer (score 5):

As Bolivia is [not yet a member of Mercosul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_states_of_Mercosur), there are no differences from any other nation for immigration, as far as I know.

The usual way is to go to Brazil with a tourist visa (usually lasts for 3 months, can be renewed for more 3) and look for a job there. With some luck, if you find a job, the hiring company can start the process with the Ministry of Labor. After that, if the Ministry granted the authorization, you have to go back to your country, get in touch with the Brazilian consulate (filling some paperwork in the meanwhile - a letter from the company that is willing to hire and a form with personal data). The consulate will then evaluate your request and eventually grant the temporary working visa.

The complete process is described [here](http://www.portalconsular.mre.gov.br/estrangeiros/tipos-de-vistos/vistos-temporarios) (in Portuguese).

You can also find some English information in the websites of Brazilian Embassies around the world (for example, [New Zealand](http://www.brazil.org.nz/page/work-visa.aspx)).

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness and as the other answer points in opposite direction, could you recheck Bolivian membership status?

Answer (score 2):

As Bolivia is a member of Mercosur you can a apply for a spacial visa as a Bolivia citizen to be able to work in any of the other countries that are Mercosur members.

http://www.mercosur.int/show?contentid=3862&channel=secretaria